# Creating directive like/dislike in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have something like this, like and dislike button,with font-awesome icons

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
    <p class="answers">{{answer.text}} <i class="fa fa-hand-o-left"  (click)="likeDislike($event,answer.id,'fa-thumbs-up')"></i></p>
  </ng-container>
```

And some function

```
  likeDislike(event: any, answerId: string, haveClass: string) {
    const hasClass = event.target.classList.contains(haveClass);
    if (hasClass) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(event.target, 'fa-thumbs-up');
      this.renderer.addClass(event.target, 'fa-thumbs-down');
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(event.target, 'fa-thumbs-down');
      this.renderer.addClass(event.target, 'fa-thumbs-up');
    }
  }
```

I dont think this is good example, can somebody help me maybe to make a directive?

Comment: sorry, I can't tell what you are trying to do or what is not working with your code. what errors are you getting?

Comment: It is working, i am toggling the icon, but i dont know this is the proper way, maybe the directive is better?

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a Component. The two-way binding is a nice extra.

**A live demo**

Check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nlms2e).

**Call it like this**

```
<app-fa-like [(liked)]='liked'></app-fa-like>
```

**Component code**

*Note: You won't need the `styles` or the `__`, it's just in here for demo purposes. Font-awesome should take care of that in your app.*

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fa-like',
  template: `
    <i 
      class='fa'
      [class.fa-thumbs-up]='liked'
      [class.fa-thumbs-down]='!liked'
      (click)='toggle()'
    >__</i>`,
  styles: [`
  .fa.fa-thumbs-up{background: green;}
  .fa.fa-thumbs-down{background: red;}
  `]
})
export class LikeComponent{
  @Input('liked') liked = true;
  @Output() likedChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  toggle(): void {
    this.liked = !this.liked;
    this.likedChange.emit(this.liked);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using angular, you have lots of options. I'm not sure any is better or worse than the others. Here's some ideas

1. Use ngClass
2. Use *ngIf
3. Use angular variable. something like this would work fine:

   ```
   <i class="fa {{answer.faFont}}" (click)="toggleIcon(answer)"></I>

   toggleIcon(answer:any) {
     answer.faFontFlg = !answer.faFontFlg;
     answer.faFont = (answer.faFontFlg)?'fa-thumbs-up':'fa-thumbs-down';
   }
   ```